# How to ensure python binaries are on your path?

Tags: python, kaggle

I am trying to use the Kaggle api. I have downloaded kaggle using pip and moved kaggle.json to ~/.kaggle, but I haven't been able to run kaggle on Command Prompt. It was not recognized. I suspect it is because I have not accomplished the step "ensure python binaries are on your path", but honestly I am not sure what it means. Here is the error message when I try to download a dataset:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> import kaggle
>>> kaggle datasets list -s demographics
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    kaggle datasets list -s demographics
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you can run command `python` in console in any folder  then `python binaries are on your path`. Better show full error which you get when you try to run `kaggle`. Maybe your problem is different. If it can't recognize command `kaggle` then you may have to use `/full/path/to/kaggle` (If you know it) (On Linux Mint I have it as `/usr/local/bin/kaggle`)

Comment: maybe you should simply uninstall `kaggle` and install it again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to download `kaggle` dataset using the `KaggleApi()` function following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgGFhQmfxHo&t=461s) but not with the `kaggle datasets` command showed in the [guide](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I wonder what the differences are

Comment: you would have to show FULL error message in question (not in comments). Maybe you installed for `Python 3` but it tries to run it with `Python 2`

Comment: I have added the error message. I have also checked my version is Python 3

Comment: `kaggle datasets list -s demographics` is NOT python command, but normal program which you have to run in console/terminal/cmd.exe. Eventually you may need to know full path and run in console/terminal/cmd.exe as `/full/path/to/kaggle datasets list -s demographics` or with python as any script `python.exe /full/path/to/kaggle datasets list -s demographics`. And if you want to use in code then you would have to read documentation or source code because it would need something like `kaggle.some_function(arguments)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kaggle` is python module but it should also install script with the same name `kaggle` which you can run in `console`/`terminal`/`powershell`/`cmd.exe` as

```
kaggle datasets list -s demographics
```

but this is NOT code which you can run in Python Shell or in Python script.

If you find this script `kaggle` and open it in editor then you can see it imports `main` from `kaggle.cli` and it runs `main()`

And this can be used in own script as

```
import sys
from kaggle.cli import main

sys.argv += ['datasets', 'list', '-s', 'demographics']
main()
```

But this method sends results directly on screen/console and it would need assign own class to `sys.stdout` to catch this text in variable.

Something like this:

```
import sys
import kaggle.cli

class Catcher():
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ''
        
    def write(self, text):
        self.text += text
 
    def close(self):
        pass
    
catcher = Catcher()    

old_stdout = sys.stdout  # keep old stdout
sys.stdout = catcher     # assing new class

sys.argv += ['datasets', 'list', '-s', 'demographics']
result = kaggle.cli.main()

sys.stdout = old_stdout  # assign back old stdout (because it is needed to run correctly `print()`

print(catcher.text)
```

---

Digging in source code on script `kaggle` I see you can do the same using

```
import kaggle.api

kaggle.api.dataset_list_cli(search='demographics')
```

but this also send all directly on screen/console.

---

**EDIT:**

You can get result as list of special objects which you can later use with `for`-loop

```
import kaggle.api

result = kaggle.api.dataset_list(search='demographics')
                                 
for item in result:
    print('title:', item.title)
    print('size:', item.size)
    print('last updated:', item.lastUpdated)
    print('download count:', item.downloadCount)
    print('vote count:', item.voteCount)
    print('usability rating:', item.usabilityRating)
    print('---')
```